# SNMP work only with localhost

Tags: snmp

how could I configure it, to work with my hostname, my ip, my domainName

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1
```

works

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public myPCname or myIP .1.3.6.1.2.1
```

doesn't work:
Timeout: No Response from myPCname or myIP

Comment: Does `ping` work with myPCname?

Comment: In addition to Keith's question, can you even ping the IP?

Comment: ping myPC
PING myPC.somewhere.co (138.111.111.1110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes frommyPC.somewhere.co (138.111.111.111): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms and same for ping 138.111.111.111, it's my IP's from ifconfig, edit: It's maybe due to firewall

Comment: well no the ports 161 are added in the firewall for udp, and even, locally it should have worked, so I have no idea, I have already uninstalled snmpd and reinstalled it.

Comment: What snmp-server is this?

Comment: Default one for ubuntu 10.04, Net-snmp

Comment: snmpd --version

NET-SNMP version:  5.4.2.1
Web:               http://www.net-snmp.org/
Email:             net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the agent configured to respond to SNMP queries externally?

Edit `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` and see if under `ACCESS CONTROL` you have community and trees allowed that would apply for external access, [check this for details](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html)

You now probably have `rocommunity public  localhost` (hence localhost works) but then another directive with `rocommunity communitysecret default -V systemonly`, try commenting this one out.

Try adding a line with `rocommunity communitystring  default` 
Then

> snmpwalk -v 1 -c communitystring myPCname or myIP .1.3.6.1.2.1

Then restart snmpd

> /etc/init.d/snmpd restart

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have problem with the community name check that and try again with this tool [snmp tool](https://www.sysaid.com/Sysforums/posts/list/2287.page)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the line :
agentaddress localhost:161
is in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf which causes snmpd listen only on the local address.
Remove it and it will be listening on all interfaces.